# pthread_cleanup not correctly calling free()

Tags: c, memory-leaks, pthreads, malloc, free

I'm having a memory leak issue with a thread. I would like to free the dat array and the buff array when the thread is cancelled or otherwise exits normally. My problem seems to be that the free call in my pthread_cleanup stack isn't executing. I know that my stack is working because my other cleanup handler function works. Any insight into what's happening here? One thought I have is to create another cleanup handler function to free things but that seems inefficient.

```
static void *dat_col(void *arg) {
  struct args *prof = (struct args *)arg;
  char *dat = NULL;
  char *buff = NULL;
  time_t start_t = 0;
  time_t cur_t = 0;
  int ret = 0;
  
  struct timespec timeout;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeout);
  timeout.tv_sec += (60 * prof->interval);
  pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, &prof->fc);
  pthread_cleanup_push(free, (void *) dat);
  pthread_cleanup_push(free, (void *) buff);

  dat = malloc(50 * prof->points);
  if (dat == NULL) {
    perror("memory error");
    goto fail;
  }
  memset(dat, 0, 50 * prof->points);
  
  buff = malloc(2);
  if (buff == NULL) {
    perror("memory error");
    goto fail;
  }
  memset(buff, 0, 2);
  

  time(&start_t);

  ret = write_port(prof->fd, "OPC?;PRES;\r", 11);
  if (ret < 0)
    goto fail;
  ret = read_port(prof->fd, buff, 2);
  if (ret < 0) {
    goto fail;
  }

  switch (prof->time_flag) {
  case 0:
    while (!exit_flag) {
      pthread_testcancel();
      ret = get_DATA(prof->fd, dat, prof->points, prof->chan, prof->fstar,
                     prof->fstop, &prof->fc);
      if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;
      memset(dat, 0, 50*prof->points);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&wait);
      pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &wait, &timeout);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&wait);
      timeout.tv_sec += (60 * prof->interval);
    }
    break;
  case 1:
    while ((difftime(start_t, cur_t) < (60 * prof->testtime)) && (!(exit_flag))) {
      pthread_testcancel();
      ret = get_DATA(prof->fd, dat, prof->points, prof->chan, prof->fstar,
                     prof->fstop, &prof->fc);
      if (ret < 0)
        goto fail;
      memset(dat, 0, 50*prof->points);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&wait);
      pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &wait, &timeout);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&wait);
      timeout.tv_sec += (60 * prof->interval);
      time(&cur_t);
    }
    break;
  }
fail:
  pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
  pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
  pthread_cleanup_pop(prof->fc);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: On a somewhat related note: Why allocate memory dynamically for `buf` if you unconditionally allocate two bytes. Why not use an array?

Comment: I need quite a few arrays in my total function, its more of a superstition than anything else. I'm still getting comfortable with C garbage collection so I like to malloc all my arrays and such.

Comment: There isn't any "garbage collection" in C. And in languages with garbage collection it happens for *dynamically* allocated objects. Defining an array as e.g. `char buf[2] = { 0 };` is really no different than declaring any other variable, like `int x = 0;`. Both are handled the same way when their life-time ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that you push ***values*** onto the cleanup stack. And when you push the values, they are null pointers, which is the values being pushed.

One solution is to use your own "free" function, and push pointers to the variables instead. Like e.g.

```
void free_indirect(void *indirect_ptr)
{
    free(*((void **) indirect_ptr));
}

// ...

pthread_cleanup_push(free_indirect, &dat);
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed the memory leak, though the compiler is warning about initialization of void(*)(void *) from void(*)(void **) even though I'm using the & operator as you suggested

Comment: @GradyWhite Writing code into answers as a hints often means it's untested, which could lead to problems like yours. Updated (and at least did a test build).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I did not understand the part "Remember that you push values onto the cleanup stack. And when you push the values, they are null pointers, which is the values being pushed.". Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @asdf When the OP is calling `pthread_cleanup_push(free, (void *) dat)` the variable `dat` is a null pointer. The OP doesn't assign to `dat` or `buff` until later, after the push calls, and then it's too late. By pushing pointers to the variables it doesn't matter when they are initialized.